# How to redirect media file on Nginx?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I have a local instance of WordPress running in Vagrant VVV. I need to redirect the uploads folder to the live site but cannot figure out how to do it the Nginx way. htaccess would be this,

```
#Redirect WordPress uploads
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://livesite.com/wp-content/uploads/$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

I tried an online converter I found but did not work.

How can I duplicate that function in Nginx locally?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest solution:

```
rewrite ^(/wp-content/uploads)(.*)$   http://livesite.com/wp-content/uploads/$2 permanent;
```

Tested and worked.